# PhoneGap 1.8.1 - Splash screen not working?

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to use this to create a splash screen, but I only get a white loading screen:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
 super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Loading...");
 super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
 super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

I've placed `splash.png` inside of all the drawable directories, but I still get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the timeout in the loadUrl line like this:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 100000);
```

that'll show the splash screen for 10 seconds.

Comment: I don't want to artificially pause the loading of the application - I just want to show a splash screen until things are ready to render.

Comment: Yeah, that is what it does...now. Check out my blog post on how I updated the splash screen for Android. http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html

Comment: Well, that explains things quite a bit.